# Augment types for imported module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, type-safety

I'm converting an existing codebase from js/react/jsx setup to TypeScript. Naturally, I'd like to do it file by file, and have a question about approaches for making TS compiler work with the existing js codebase.

I convert file `index.js` but want to leave `foo.js` in JavaScript for now:

```
// index.ts

import { fooFunction } from 'foo';

foo({ val: 1 });
```

---

```
// foo.js

export const fooFunction = ({ val, optionalProp }) => {
  //...
}
```

The problem in this example that TypeScript automatically infers argument to `foo` and complains that `Property 'optionalProp' is missing in type { val:string, optionalProp:any }`

Needing to "stub" the type of `fooFunction` sent me looking and I found a few ways i may be able to do it:

**1) Use require instead of import**

```
// index.ts
var fooFunction: any = require('foo').fooFunction;
```

**2) Merge declarations**

```
?
```

**3) Add a d.ts file with custom declarations for `foo`** - haven't attempted but seems inconvenient

Ideally I don't have to do **(1)** because I want to keep using import syntax and I don't have to do **(3)** because that will require me to add declaration files only to remove them later when I'm ready to convert `foo`.

**(2)** sounds awesome, but I can't figure out a working solution.

```
// index.ts

declare module 'foo' {
  function fooFunction(options: any): any
}
```

Doesn't work and throws `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fooFunction'`

How do I do that? Are there docs that have examples of what I'm trying to do and/or have more explanation about declaration merging and how to work with [namespace/interface/value](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)?
Are there better approaches for incrementally transitioning to TypeScript?

Comment: For those who may have the same question, I opted for using declaration files. For this example, file `foo.d.ts`. So, now I have `foo.d.ts` and `foo.js`. When converting `foo.js` to TS later, the declaration file will likely become unnecessary, so plan to remove it

Answer (score 0):

This may not work, just wanted to preface this with that - I don't know much at all about React - but I know for sure that you can use `?` on a variable to make it "optional". I've used this before in functions

```
myFooFunction(requiredParam: typeA, optionalParam?: typeB) { ... }
```

Another thing you should consider is the fact that Typescript can add some type checking at compile time, so IMO you should leverage that as much as possible.

Edit: to work with the optional parameter, you could just check that it exists.

```
myFooFunction(requiredParam: typeA, optionalParam?: typeB) {
  if (optionalParam) { // if this results to true, the param was given
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that but `fooFunction` in `foo.js` is pure JavaScript, not TypeScript